# How to leave semantic-ui sidebar opened

Tags: javascript, sidebar, semantic-ui

I now have a sidebar which opens with a button.

html:

```
<div class="ui left sidebar"><a class="item">Home</a></div>
<div class="pusher">&nbsp;</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.left.sidebar')
.sidebar('setting', {
    dimPage             : false,
    transition          : 'push',
    mobileTransition    : 'push'})
.sidebar('attach events', '#show-menu');
```

How can I prevent the sidebar to close when the user clicks somewhere on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found a fiddle which helped me figuring this one out.

http://jsfiddle.net/8f11gjez/1/

It seems that if you add the styles

```
<div class="ui left sidebar overlay visible"><a class="item">Home</a></div>
<div class="pusher">&nbsp;</div>
```

the only problem is the overlay on the pusher but I'll fix that with a media query for the device and add padding to the pusher style.

Answer (score 2):

set closable property to false:

```
$('.ui.sidebar').sidebar({
  dimPage: false,
  closable: false
}).sidebar('show');
```